# Google Chrome: display/list enabled extensions only?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have ≈ 100 extensions installed in Chrome but less than 10 is enabled and maybe half of them are enabled in incognito mode.

Is it possible to just list enabled extension and/or just list extensions enabled in incognito?

Comment: Not possible on `chrome://extensions` page, but you can use `management` Chrome extensions API to list extensions with certain specifications.

Comment: What is "management"?

Comment: See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management